# how to use express Session

Tags: node.js

I am a express freshman, I have a problem with session now. this code I can't store seesion. req.session.user is undefined, maybe the quession was the session not store. what's wrong of my code, please tell me my wrong please thanks

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}))
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.user);  **this is undefined**
    if (req.session && req.session.user === "amy" && req.session.admin)
        return next();
    else
        return res.sendStatus(401);
};
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.query.username || !req.query.password) {
        res.send('login failed');
    } else if(req.query.username === "amy" || req.query.password === "amyspassword") {
        req.session.user = "amy";
        req.session.admin = true;
        res.send(req.session.user);
    }
});
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.send("logout success!");
});
app.get('/content', auth, function (req, res) {
    res.send("You can only see this after you've logged in.");
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Where is it undefined? What line?

Comment: auth  midware session is undefined

Comment: What happens when you console.log just req.session?

Comment: I local host:3000/login?username=amy&&password=amyspassword"

Comment: Look at my answer and let me know if that works for you. Also that URL format isn't correct. Try `http://localhost:3000/login?username=amy&password=amyspassword`

Comment: i visit localhost:3000/login?username=amy&&password=amyspassword make a  session ( session.user =amy session.admin=true )but the session is undefined when i visit localhost:3000/content i dont know where is  wrong

Comment: Did you look at my answer and try my solution? Again also your URL is incorrect. Please try the URL above with the answer below that I submitted.

Comment: charlie fish i try your url but it's not work

Comment: Did you try the code below? Removing `cookie: { secure: true }`?

Comment: yes ，I delete  cookie: { secure: true } but it not work

Comment: And after removing that it gives you the same problem?

Comment: Ok I just updated my answer. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the current code you have for using express session try the following code.

```
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

`secure: true` although a recommended option requires an https-enabled website. HTTPS is necessary for storing secure cookies. If you set that option to true while using an HTTP only site without HTTPS the cookie will not be set which is why you were running into problems. The [GitHub repo for express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) has some more detail regarding this.

So changing your code to that should work. Let me know if that doesn't make sense or if it still gives you problems.

**EDIT**

Try also the following line of code inside your get `/login` route from:

```
res.send(req.session.user);
```

To this:

```
res.redirect('/content');
```

**EDIT 2**

To not have it automatically redirect but still save the session try the code below.

```
req.session.save();
res.send("test");
```

Comment: hello I delete res.send(req.session.user); and  res.redirect('/content'); but  I visit localhost:3000/content the auth midware is failed session is undefined

Comment: [Join this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120646/how-to-use-express-session). If you could click that link and join the chat it would be easier for me to help you out instead of spamming the comments.

Comment: sorry how to chat   You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Comment: My bad. I think since you don't have 20 reputation we can't do it that way. One moment.

Comment: Ok here is [my code](https://gist.github.com/fishcharlie/04ef112d4fce79686962f56afafa479c). Can you try replacing your code with my code and let me know if that works?

Comment: Also can you explain exactly what happens? When you go to `http://localhost:3000/login?username=amy&password=amyspassword` what shows up in your browser and what shows up in your terminal?

Comment: Is it still giving you problems?

Comment: it 's work  but i don't know why i must use rediect('/connent") i think i visit http://localhost:3000/login?username=amy&password=amyspassword i make a session ,when i visit another url the session can help authentic,and in chrome the "session storge" is null

Comment: There we go. Just made an edit. You need to save the session if you don't want to use a redirect. Remember to accept this answer if it helped you :) and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I am stackoverflow freshman how to accept your answer : (  thank you

Comment: Just click the check box near the top left side of the answer to accept it. No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: Yep that means you accepted it. Thanks so much. Glad I could help.